# 2D vector with aligned allocator syntax problem

Tags: c++, opencl

I am completely stuck when I am trying to put the value of 2D vector into another 2D vector. The code execution just exit. Putting a little extra code to make things more clear.

```
int data_size_val= 8;
int n_qubits_val = ceil(log2(data_size_val));
int n_states_val = pow(2, n_qubits_val);
vector<vector<float, aligned_allocator<float> >> source_phi;

vector<vector<float>> phi_val;

for(int i=0;i< n_states_val/2;i++){
vector<float> temp;
for(int j=0;j< n_qubits_val;j++){
temp.push_back(0);
}
phi_val.push_back(temp);
}
 for(int i=0;i< n_states_val/2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j< n_qubits_val;j++){
    source_phi[i][j]= phi_val[i][j];           // This is where Code Exit execution
    }
 }
```

It would be really great if I can be helped to resolve this issue. I think, there is some problem with syntax of 2D vector "source_phi".

Comment: Thank you @AdrianMole for your response. I am allocating the values of phi_val[i][j] into source_phi[i][j]. Is this is a problem in the syntax?  Please guide.

Comment: @AdrianMole I think, there is a need to define the size of source_phi. But I donot know the correct syntax.

Comment: @AdrianMole The existing vendor code I am editing is only for a 1D vector. But I need a 2D vector in my application.

Comment: @AdrianMole I think, I should try push_back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `source_phi` is an **empty** vector of **empty** vectors. So, the `source_phi[i][j]= phi_val[i][j]` assignment is attempting to assign a value to a non-existent element of a non-existent vector.

There are several ways you can handle this. One is to use the `push_back` and `temp` approach that you used when initialising the `phi_val` vector in the first set of nested `for` loops:

```cpp
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < n_states_val / 2; i++) {
        vector<float, aligned_allocator<float>> temp; // Create empty temporary...
        for (int j = 0; j < n_qubits_val; j++) {
            temp.push_back(phi_val[i][j]); // Push data into the temporary
        }
        source_phi.push_back(temp); // Now push that temp into the outer vector
    }
```

An alternative (and likely more efficient) approach is to call the `.resize()` member function on: (1) the outer vector (before the outer `for` loop) and (2) on the inner vectors, on each run through that loop (before the inner loop):

```cpp
    source_phi.resize(n_states_val / 2); // Allocates space for each vector
    for (int i = 0; i < n_states_val / 2; i++) {
        source_phi[i].resize(n_qubits_val); // Allocates space for each element
        for (int j = 0; j < n_qubits_val; j++) {
            source_phi[i][j] = phi_val[i][j]; // The LHS now exists and can be assigned
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Adrian Mole for the great help. Your push_back logic fixed the problem.

Comment: @Manu But note that the second approach is better, especially if your vectors are large. Calling `push_back` frequently will likely mean lots of internal reallocations for the vectors' memory. If you know the final size in advance, it's better to allocate the required memory before the loops.